# Are all applications developed with versions prior to 20.1 vulnerable?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a restaurant management system with many pages with forms and interactive grids to create documents like sales invoices, return goods, etc... . The problem arises when user clicks the submit button many times quickly by mistake or intentionally, which results in many submissions to the same transaction.
There is a bug  Bug 26475905 filed for that and fixed in 20.1 which you can see if you have Oracle Support.
All solutions for this are client-side solutions like disabling the submit button after submit or showing the spinning wheel through a dynamic action after submit.
The only server-side solution is to change page's "reload on submit" attribute to "Always" after setting "enable duplicate page submission" to "No". Unfortunately, that solution does not work when the page contains interactive grids.
Which eventually let me think that every application developed with 18.2 and earlier versions can be manipulated somehow, am I right? Or is there a reliable solution that I did not come across after surfing the web for months.
I edited the thread title from "Are all applications developed with 18.2 vulnerable?" to "Are all applications developed with versions prior to 20.1 vulnerable?"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a Dynamic Action to disable the button on click event and then submit the page.
This will prevent multiple submissions

Comment: It's a client side solution which I mentioned in the question. The page can still be manipulated somehow.